# Highlight menu with specifics components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have problem with highlight menu item when section is visible on viewport. I have 2 components:
Parent component and Child component with sticky menu. In parent component I fetch data from cms where this component looks like this:

```
      <MainLayout> 

          <HeroBanner 

            {...props} 

          /> 

           <MainContent> 

               <Data> 

             //fetched data from cms 

                <div id=1> 

                    <h2> title </h2> 

                    <p> title </p> 

                </div> 

                </ Data > 

              )} 

          </MainContent> 

          <AsideContent> 

             Nav data={data} />} 

          </AsideContent> 

        </MainLayout>
```

Second component (child component it’s Nav

```
    Return( 
      <ScickyNav>
        {data && 

          data.map((item, index) => { 

            if (item.type == 'sectionHeading' && item.value) { 

              return ( 

                <p className={item.value.anchorName} key={index} > 

                  <Link> 

                    {item.value.linkText} 

                  </Link> 

                </p> 

          ); 

      } 
    </StickyNav>

);
```

I don’t have idea how to highlight Link maybe somebody has idea how to do this?